# Model.aggregate, $filter even when condition is empty

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm passing query params to a mongoose $filter.

url: `projecttest?assigned_to=jack&created_by=bob&open=true`

- The `$filter` condition must be an `$and` because any number of
  params can be passed in the url.
- Currently if a param is not passed
  in the url, the `$filter` does not return anything. All `$filter`
  conditions must be met because of the `$and`.

If a param is **NOT** passed, what can I set it to, so that a non existing param does not break my `$filter`?

- I've tried `''` and `null`.
- I've tried building up the `$cond` list using a
  map() function, but it outputs a string and the `$filter` does not
  accept this.
  queryArray = queryParams.map(o => {
    return `{$eq: [$$item.${Object.keys(o)}, "${Object.values(o)}" ]}`;
  })

*Project* is a mongoose model and I am filtering an array called *issues* inside the mongo document.

```
    Project.aggregate(
        [
          {
            $match: {
              'project_title': 'projecttest'
            }
          }, {
            $project: {
              issue: {
                $filter: {
                  input: '$issues', 
                  as: 'item', 
                  cond: { $and:                        
                  [
                    {$eq: ['$$item.assigned_to', assigned_to ]} ,
                    {$eq: ['$$item.created_by', created_by ]},
                    {$eq: ['$$item.open', open ]},
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
          }
        ]
    ).exec((err, issues) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        return res.json(issues[0].issue);
    })
```

Comment: You can build the object from your params first and then pass it to `cond`.

Comment: I already have an object.... req.query which looks like
{ assigned_to: 'tom', created_by: 'bob' }. Passing that to $filter does not work - it returns everything unfiltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the object from your `req.query` first and then pass it to `cond`:

Example:

```
let cond = Object.entries(req.query).map(el => {$eq: [`$$item.${el[0]}`, el[1] ]});
Project.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          'project_title': 'projecttest'
        }
      }, {
        $project: {
          issue: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$issues', 
              as: 'item', 
              cond: { $and: cond}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
).exec((err, issues) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    return res.json(issues[0].issue);
})
```

Comment: Thank you Cuong. I had tried building my own `cond`. But unsuccessfully. I think I had been outputting a string and the `cond` didn't understand. I revisited this idea again and  only needed to make a minor change to your suggestion:       

let cond = Object.entries(req.query).map(el => {
        return {$eq: [`$$item.${el[0]}`, el[1] ]};
});

This version seems to output something that the `cond` accepts.